# Outlook JS Add-in - Pass data from taskpane to event

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I need help creating an outlook JS Add-in that can forward mails.

**The idea**
In a taskpane a list of mail addresses is shown that the user can click on.
At the click event the mail should be forwarded to the one the user clicked on.

**Current state**
The Add-in opens a reply window using `Office.context.mailbox.item?.displayReplyAllFormAsync()`.
With the `onNewMessageCompose` event I want to change the recipient so that the user only has to click on "Send".
I try to find a work around so that I do not have to use the Graph API.

**The issue**
How can I pass e. g. the mail address from the taskpane JS code to the `onNewMessageComposeHandler` e. g. with a "global" storage both have access to?

<s>I already tried using the local storage and the roaming settings. Both did not work.</s>
**Update: Thanks to the answer of "Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT" I found the mistake:
When using the roaming storage and you set a value, you have to call saveAsync() afterwards.**

According to the offical [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtimes#types-of-runtimes) shared runtimes aren't supported:

> An Outlook add-in that has the following features has as many as four runtimes. **Shared runtimes aren't supported in Outlook.**
>
> - A task pane
> - A function command
> - An event-based task [...]
> - A dialog [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Roaming Settings to do this. The roaming setting can be set in your taskpane file and fetched in your LaunchEvent file. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/metadata-for-an-outlook-add-in#loading-roaming-settings

Browser session storage can also be used similarly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  
I did get it to work with the roaming settings.  
My mistake was not to call the `saveAsync` function.